# postgres auto_explain : setting log_min_duration doesn't start

Tags: postgresql, explain

postgres 8.4.20

With these settings, the daemon starts :

> postgresql.conf
>
> shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'

With these settings, the daemon doesn't start :

> postgresql.conf
>
> shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'
>
> auto_explain.log_min_duration = 1000

It is a server with a legacy application, so we cannot upgrade PG.
I cannot find documentation of this behaviour / bug...

Comment: What message do you get in the log file?

Comment: It aborts too early. I tried with log_destination = 'stderr' and after log_destination = 'syslog' but no output.

Comment: Did you set `custom_variable_classes = 'auto_explain'` in the postgresql.conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put also this setting and it solved :

> custom_variable_classes = 'auto_explain'

Comment: Missing that line does produce output to the server log.  You should figure out why you can't find the log output, as you will surely run into other problems in the future for which it would be helpful.